# Need help vertically centering a Bootstrap form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create an html admin login page. I'm new to Bootstrap and CSS am having difficulty centering the form and adjusting the spacing.

The html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Administrator Login</h2>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--Container-->
```

In my CSS I only changed the background color of the page and centered the h2 heading. Currently, the form is really wide and when I adjust the width in the CSS, the form becomes uncentered.

```
form { width: 500px; }
```

1. I want the form to be centered exactly in the middle. Right now it's centered horizontally but not vertically.
2. I want to readjust the width of the form.
3. I want to readjust the width of the button. I don't want it the same length as the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste what CSS you have so far? If it's just `form { width: 500px; }` I don't see how it's even centered horizontally. Feel free to add this fiddle to your question as well: http://jsfiddle.net/ktkoygzx/

Comment: @Mike The only CSS I have is `body { background-color: #eee }` and `h2 { text-align: center; }` From what I understood, it's centered horizontally due to the Bootstrap grid system? At least it seems that way on my browser. The html is:  `<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">`

Comment: I see what you mean. There's nothing that's actually centering the form, but since it uses up 100% width it appears centered.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you center the form :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">ur code here</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Your provided code made the width of my form shorter but didn't really change its location. It was already centered horizontally. Any idea how to center it vertically?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container-wrap{
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-wrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
            <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Administrator Login</h2>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
            <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--Container-->
  </div><!-- container-wrap-->
```

this is how achieved to make form center aligned on screen.

Regards

Comment: This doesn't center align vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

### CSS

```
.outer {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 outer">
            <form class="form-signin">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Administrator Login</h2>
                <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
                <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus />
                <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ktkoygzx/1/).

Answer (score 0):

here it is how i center align the form horizontaly and vertically

```
   /* css */

   body{
        width:960px;
        margin:0 auto;
      }
     .container-wrap{
         display:block;
         margin-top:25%;
         background:#999;
         padding-bottom:40px;
       }
        .container-wrap input{
           margin-bottom:10px;
         }

<!--html code-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <div class="container-wrap">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
           <form class="form-signin">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Administrator Login</h2>
            <label for="inputUsername" class="sr-only">Username</label>
           <input type="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
           <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
         <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
         <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div><!--Container-->
 </div><!-- container-wrap-->
```

i hope this will help you understand how it works.

Regards